# NuGet package missing in release yet it compiles

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, nuget

I've been building a Xamarin.Forms application and using Debug to build this entire time. Everything in it works OK.

However, today, when I went to build Release, everything built fine. However, a menu item I'd clickーwhich should open an [Acr.UserDialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) dialog, would not do anything, no matter how many times I clicked the item. Again, this works perfectly in the Debug build.

My best guess is the Acr.UserDialogs NuGet reference is somehow not making it into the Release build. This sounds absurd, but it's the only logical explanation I can think of, as all other selectable menu options work perfectly (none of which create any dialogs).

I even uninstalled and reinstalled the NuGet package with no difference in functionality. Is it even possible for that to happen?

I remember having to downgrade Xamarin.Forms due to menu item tapping not working correctly for groups, but this isn't even a ListViewGroup, and as I said, the other menu items function correctly.

Comment: I noticed the latest version uses .net standard.  I wonder if that has anything to do with it.  Anyway,  if you put some other native dialogue in the event you could see if the code is reaching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was my own dumbness.

The line that created the dialog was in a Task which ran on a non-UI thread. For some reason Debug was fine with this, but Release wasn’t. An exception was being thrown on the Task so it wouldn’t complete, and that’s why nothing happened.

I refactored the code so only the stuff that needs to be run on a different thread goes in the Task so that the UI isn’t blocked.